# How to transform a Seq[State[S,A]] into State[S, A]

Tags: monads, scalaz

Is there an existing combinator to perform that.

Here is my existing code

```
  private def traverse(states: Seq[State[Set[Tip], Unit]]) : State[Set[Tip], Unit] = {
    states.reduce((a,b) => for { _ <- a
                                 bb <- b } yield bb)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a simpler syntax for monadic bind that ignores the value from the first monad—`>>`:

```
import scalaz.State
import scalaz.syntax.monad._

val states: List[State[Set[Tip], Unit]] = ???

states.reduce((a, b) => a >> b)
```

But there is also a special method to do what you want, namely `Foldable.sequenceS_`:

```
import scalaz.State
import scalaz.std.iterable._
import scalaz.syntax.foldable._

val states: List[State[Set[Tip], Unit]] = ???

states.sequenceS_[Set[Tip], Unit]
```